# Why is Generic Interrupt Controller in ARM Cortex A15 Multi-Core processor frequency less than main core frequency?

Tags: arm, interrupt

I was studying about Generic Interrupt Controllers(GIC) in ARM and when I read about the Clock frequency for GIC, it stated that a GIC has a clock frequency that is an integer multiple less than that of Main core clock frequency. Can somebody explain why is it so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highspeed circuits are a LOT harder to design, manufacture and control. So, if speed is not that important (As it is the case with your GIC), the peripherals of the core will usually run a lot slower than the core itself. Even L2-Cache usually does not run with full core speed.

Also, the gain of having a faster clocked GIC is probably negligible, so there is no reason for the designers to do a new generation, which in this business always is an expensive and risky adventure.

Comment: Good answer.
Also - higher frequency means higher power consumption. So if you're in any way power- (or thermally) constrained, it helps to keep parts of the SoC not vital to your overall performance running slightly slower.

Comment: Another point is that the *GIC* clock is divided down (or possibly up with a PLL) so that the edge of the *GIC* will co-incide with a main CPU clock. +1 Easier design, manufacture, single clock source, lower power with little loss of functionality.